# My laptop can' t find ubuntu on the harddrive when trying too boot

Tags: boot, hard-drive

A while ago I tried to install ubuntu alongside my school laptop to to see what it was. I deleted it eventually since the laptop didn't like dual boot (ubuntu didn't boot a couple of times). Now ( after a couple of years just using windows), I wanted to use ubuntu as the only OS on my laptop. I used a live USB, installed everything, and when prompted to restart I did. Only to find out, it didn' t boot. I used the USB again because I thought I did something wrong, but when I chose the option to install ubuntu, it asked me if I wanted to overwrite the existing Ubuntu system. I did, since I thought the first install might be corrupted or something, but when I tried to boot the laptop after installing the fresh version, it still wouldn't boot.

So, my question is (after this whole story): what am I doing wrong? the BIOS doesn't recognize an OS on my harddrive I think. I saw other threads that said to use boot repair, but I got an error that said that the system is in BIOS compatible mode or something.. I also tried to see how the partitions are divided using Gparted. I will leave a screenshot here, because I think there is something wrong in the partitions with the GRUB loader or something like that. But I don't have the knowledge to see what I'm looking for..

If anyone could help me out, it would be really appreciated!

Thanks in advance..[the screenshot of GParted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8WtKw.png)

Comment: What brand/model system? You show both an ESP - efi system partition for UEFI boot & bios_grub for BIOS/CSM/Legacy boot. If system is UEFI & Windows is UEFI, you need to install Ubuntu in UEFI boot mode, not BIOS. Be sure to boot live installer flash drive in UEFI mode. Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Bootinfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.Lets see details, use ppa version with your USB installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have an old Toshiba satellite. I don’t think my laptop has UEFI since it’s so old, but I’m not sure.. alright I’ll leave the pastebin link! Thanks for your help!

Comment: I’m going to find out whether my laptop has BIOS or EUFI. Then I’ll make the USB have UEFI or BIOS. Is that what you mean? Sorry for all the questions

Comment: I have seen where newest Ubuntu installer creates an ESP, even with BIOS installs. So having an ESP, is not definitive, anymore on whether install is UEFI. You say old, but Microsoft has required vendors to install Windows in UEFI boot mode since 2012. So even a 10 year old system will be UEFI. A few a little older were also UEFI as vendors started to use UEFI with last year or two of Windows 7 installs. Those very early UEFI systems needed updates & eventually work arounds to get them to work. Some early UEFI systems then did work better with old BIOS install.

Comment: I’ve used efibootmgr in the live environment to see if my laptop supports EFi files, and it said that my laptop didnt support efi files. Yeah I know, my laptop is really old haha. So I have to find a way to make the Ubuntu installation BIOS instead of EFI I guess? Can you download the installation file as a BIOS file or do you have to specify the .iso file as BIOS file when you copy the file to a bootable usb?

Comment: If system is BIOS only, then installer will only boot in BIOS mode. Some tools create installer in UEFI only or BIOS only, but most create it so it can boot either way. Then when booting live installer from UEFI/BIOS you have to choose whether you want UEFI or BIOS. BIOS only systems would not have that choice.

Answer (score 1):

What I see is that your Ubuntu partition is mounting as `/boot-...` ( I cannot see more on the picture than that ). This should be mounted as `/`. Try to change the mountpoint in `GParted` ( from Live environment ).
It also is important to know if your computer uses a BIOS or UEFI. If you know that make the installation medium according to that.

You could edit the `/etc/fstab` file in a text editor like such as `gedit` or `subl`, or you could just do this:

1 Make sure the Hard Drive is connected.
2 Open Disks.
3 Click on the Hard Drive you want to modify.
4 Click on the Partition you want to modify.
5 Click on the gear icon.
6 Click on Edit Mount Options.
7 Move the Automatic Mount Options slider to Off.
8 Type in the path you want the Partition mounted too in the Mount Point text box.
9 Click the OK button.
10 Type in the super-user password.
 This will make the necessary changes to the /etc/fstab file for you.
The easiest thing to do however is reinstall the system. Make backups of important files first. Then do a complete format of the entire disk. During install let the setup procedure/system decide how to partition the disk. That way you will end up with a working OS on your computer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! How do I change the mountpoint? Sorry for all the questions, I’m a noob haha and with live environment you mean the “try ubuntu” option instead of the complete install?

Comment: Yes, the 'Try Ubuntu' option takes you to the Live Environment.

Comment: See also my edited answer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I don’t have any files on Ubuntu so a clean install is no problem. I’m gonna try that first, and if it doesn’t work I’m gonna try the other method you described. Thanks for your help!

Comment: If the answer from Joepie Es works please accept it. If you like you can give it an arrow up as well.

Comment: Yeah I tried but I don't have enough reputation to do that..